# Regular expression to find, copy and insert at end

Tags: html, regex, notepad++, dreamweaver

I have a large TOC in HTML as an unordered list.  Each anchor tag in the list has its own individual id attribute.  Possibly using either Dreamweaver or notepad++ I want to be able to find the id attribute, copy it and place it after the hash (.html#) set up in the href attribute so the long TOC will scroll to the position in which the page it has navigated to.

So for the example below:

```
<li><a id="a4.9" href="trigger_marker.html#">Trigger marker</a> </li>
<li><a id="a4.10" href="timedelayarrow.html#">Time-delay arrow</a> </li>
<li><a id="a4.11" href="spectrumview.html#">Spectrum view</a> </li>
```

I would like the outcome to be:

```
<li><a id="a4.9" href="trigger_marker.html#a4.9">Trigger marker</a> </li>
<li><a id="a4.10" href="timedelayarrow.html#a4.10">Time-delay arrow</a> </li>
<li><a id="a4.11" href="spectrumview.html#a4.11">Spectrum view</a> </li>
```

Any help is as always very much appreciated, apologies at my lack of attempt on this but regular expressions are the only way I suspect I may be able to achieve this and I have little to no experience knowledge of regexes.

Comment: Use this `(?<=id=")([^"\n]+)"[^#\n]+#\K` [Link](https://regex101.com/r/TTPhuz/4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

`(?<=id=")([^"\n]+)"[^#\n]+#\K`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TTPhuz/4)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=id=")` - Positive lookbehind searching for the position which is preceded by `id="`
- `([^"\n]+)` - Matching 1+ occurrences of any character which is neither `"` nor a newline character and capturing it in group
- `"` - matches `"` literally
- `[^#\n]+` - matching 1+ occurrences of any character which is neither a `#` nor a newline character
- `#` - matches `#` literally
- `\K` - Forget everything matched so far. Here, we get the position where we have to insert what was captured in group 1.

After replacement,

[image]

Comment: Any reason for down-voting? Anything I need to correct in the regex?

Comment: Oh my word! Gurman, you are a legend.  Thank you so much, and the explanation is very much appreciated as I need to pull my finger out and get to grips with regex.  A thousand Thank you's, it works perfectly!

Comment: I upvoted and accepted as answer, is it not playing ball, what have I done wrong??

Comment: You don't need to cover the `id="` in a lookbehind, as you discard the whole match at the end anyways and regular matching is to preferred over lookarounds, performance wise (not that this would make a huge difference here)

Comment: @SebastianProske Thanks for the inputs. Will keep this in mind. [Updated Regex here](https://regex101.com/r/TTPhuz/5)